# build.exe and cleaning?

Tags: windows, drivers

I'm working on some driver development and using Microsoft's build.exe tool from the WDK 6001 (Vista). I'd like to be able to clean up all the object and intermediate files it spews out on every iteration.

So far, I've found "build.exe -0 -c" works relatively well, by simply deleting all the .obj files, but none of the .sbr files or directories it created. I'd really like to avoid writing a makefile as another makefile would be hard to integrate into the build system.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you though of a scripting language to to a recursive delete. We use Nant for our build system, and that has this type of thing built in.

A more windows answer might be to use [powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6EF4735-C7DE-46A2-997A-EA58FDFCBA63&displaylang=en) which you should be able to call from your makefile.

Or you could just revert to DOS commands. Thus

```
dir /S *.sbr
```

Shows me all my nested sbr files, and then

```
del /S *.sbr
```

deletes then all. And can be shown to have worked via the dir command again.